# Is it possible to use the SLI/Crossfire PCI Express slot for an expansion card that is not graphics?

Tags: motherboard, sata, pci-express

Is it possible to configure the PCI Express lanes in a P67 motherboard to 8x/8x and use the second slot for a 4x SATA card (for example) instead of another graphics card?

Answer (score 0):

I have never tried this, however I can't think of a reason this wouldn't work.

You should be able to put a single PCI Express x1, x2, x4, x8, or x16 card into a x16 PCI Express slot. The chipset should recognize that the card is not a video card and not enable SLI or Crossfire. If this isn't the case see if you can disable SLI and Crossfire within the BIOS.

Sorry I couldn't give you a definitive answer.

Comment: I would try it myself if I had a P55 or P67 motherboard with that possibility, but I don't.  My current motherboard has an older chipset with only one x16 slot period, and doesn't have the capability to split even if it had a second.  The reason I'm asking the question is to help me decide which motherboard to go with when I make the jump to Sandy Bridge.  The ability to use a x8 slot hooked up directly to the CPU (instead of having to go through the  somewhat anemic DMI link to the chipset) for arbitrary purposes could be handy for expansion purposes in the future.